# "No DEX File Found" Error While generating APK in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, export, apk

When generating apk file from eclipse error comes up saying "No DEX File Found" and I have Checked "Skip packaging and dexing" but still comes up with the error.

Please help!

Answer (score 4):

Just go to Window > Preferences > Android > Build > [Uncheck] Skip packaging and dexing until export to launch.

[Source](http://jquerymobiletuts.blogspot.com/2016/09/how-to-fix-no-dex-file-found.html)